# Learning Python: Printing Variable Key Arguments

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that can take and print a variable number of arguments. The code is below. My code works, however, the format of the output is not what I am trying to achieve. Can someone help me work around the output?

Desired output:

```
{'first': 'Steve', 'last': 'Cook'}
```

My output:

```
first:Steve

last:Cook
```

```
def full_name(**data):
   for key, value in data.items():
      print(f"{key}:{value}")
    
first = input()
last = input()
    
full_name(first = first, last = last)
```

Comment: I formatted your code and output: it was not indented properly. Can you check that I have done it correctly.

Comment: You'll get the output you want if you just print the dictionary instead of looping over it.

Comment: Why do you want that format? That *looks* like the regular format of a Python `dict` string representation, so you could just `print(data)`

Comment: Yes this looks much better, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apparently went too far I guess? This is the proper coding, thanks everyone for the help.

```
def full_name(**data):
    print(data)

first = input()
last = input()

full_name(first = first, last = last)
```